# How do I create a Web Framework?

Tags: html, css, web, web-frameworks

I am an intern in one company and they told me to create a prototype of a Website. They wanted me to use Java Play or Node.js for it. They wanted me to "Port your project into some complete web framework and host it on your computer". How do I do this? I tried looking for tutorials on Google and on Youtube but there's none.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they're asking you to create a web framework.  Perhaps they are wanting you to use an existing framework for Node.js (such as Express.js. which is a Node.js framework)?   Also, "Play" is a Java framework.

My best guess is that they want you to choose a framework and port your project into either Node.js or Java on your computer.  Unless you know Node.js, Java is probably an easier approach.

Frameworks assist you in the development process.  Java (a language) and Node.js (a runtime environment) are used to actually develop web applications.

Comment: I still don't get it. So where do I start? Like what software do I need? I really need to submit this today..

Comment: download Play: https://www.playframework.com/ and read through their documentation for how to create a web app.

Comment: I just installed Node.js and express.js. I copied my html, css, javascript and image files to the folder I created with Express/Node.js. Why does this guy on youtube have .hjs instead of .html for his html files?

Comment: .hjs is type of javascript template (i.e. not html).

Comment: I'm sorry. Okay my web app is complete but they want me to host it with my computer. How is that done? I tried signing up and paying for a membership at DigitalOcean but I didn't know how to set it up so I ended up canceling my account. Is there any other alternative to that that is easier to use?